# Getting a Specified Cast is not valid while importing data from Excel using Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, asp.net-4.0

This is my second post. After learning from  my first post how fantastic is to use Linq to SQL, I wanted to try to import data from a Excel sheet into my SQL database.

First My Excel Sheet:

it contains 4 columns namely

- ItemNo
- ItemSize
- ItemPrice
- UnitsSold

I have a created a database table with the following fields

```
table name ProductsSold
  Id int not null identity --with auto increment set to true
  ItemNo VarChar(10) not null
  ItemSize VarChar(4) not null
  ItemPrice Decimal(18,2) not null
  UnitsSold int not null
```

Now I created a dal.dbml file based on my database and I am trying to import the data from excel sheet to db table using the code below.

Everything is happening on click of a button.

```
   private const string forecast_query = "SELECT ItemNo, ItemSize, ItemPrice, UnitsSold FROM [Sheet1$]";

    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var importer = new LinqSqlModelImporter();

        if (fileUpload.HasFile)
        {
            var uploadFile = new UploadFile(fileUpload.FileName);

            try
            {
                fileUpload.SaveAs(uploadFile.SavePath);
                if(File.Exists(uploadFile.SavePath))
                {
                    importer.SourceConnectionString = uploadFile.GetOleDbConnectionString();
                    importer.Import(forecast_query);
                    gvDisplay.DataBind();
                    pnDisplay.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 Response.Write(ex.Source.ToString());
                lblInfo.Text = ex.Message;

            }
           finally
            {
                uploadFile.DeleteFileNoException();
            }


        }
    }

    // Now here is the code for LinqSqlModelImporter

     public class LinqSqlModelImporter : SqlImporter
{
    public override void Import(string query)
    {
        // importing data using oledb command and inserting into db using LINQ to SQL
        using (var context = new WSDALDataContext())
        {
            using (var myConnection = new OleDbConnection(base.SourceConnectionString))
            using (var myCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection))
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                var myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    context.ProductsSolds.InsertOnSubmit(new ProductsSold()
                    {
                        ItemNo = myReader.GetString(0),
                        ItemSize = myReader.GetString(1),
                        ItemPrice = myReader.GetDecimal(2),
                        UnitsSold = myReader.GetInt32(3)

                    });

                }
            }

            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }

}
```

can someone please tell me where am I making the error or if I am missing something, but this is driving me nuts.

When I debugged I am getting this error

> when casting from a number the value must be a number less than infinity

I really appreciate it

Comment: Where (on which line) are you getting that error?

Comment: when I used the debugger, it's show on line 23 for the LinqSqlModelImporter which is  context.ProductsSolds.InsertOnSubmit(new ProductsSold()
                    {
                        ItemNo = myReader.GetString(0),
                        ItemSize = myReader.GetString(1),
                        ItemPrice = myReader.GetDecimal(2),
                        UnitsSold = myReader.GetInt32(3)

                    });

Comment: So I am thinking may be it has do with something either with GetDecimal or GetInt32. this is my enter error "   at System.Data.OleDb.ColumnBinding.ValueString()\r\n   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.GetString(Int32 ordinal)\r\n   at WS.DAL.LinqSqlModelImporter.Import(String query) in Projects\\WSModel\\WS.DAL\\LinqSqlModelImporter.cs:line 23\r\n   at WSModel._Default.btnUpload_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in \\WSModel\\Default.aspx.cs:line 35"

Comment: where line 35 is importer.Import(forecast_query);

Comment: I would add a Watch on `GetValue` for each column and see what the source value is.  You might also use `GetProviderSpecificFieldType` to get the type that it's expecting.  Excel can be quirky when defining field types.

Comment: Is there anyway you can show me an example in adding a Watch on GetValue,I am still in the learning Process. Thanks and appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options:

- [Add a watch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx) on `myReader.GetValue(0)`, `myReader.GetValue(1)`,
  etc. to see what the source value is.  Add a breakpoint on the line
  that's throwing the error and see which value is causing the issue.
- Change your object initializer to separate calls to see which column is throwing the error:

> 

```
ProductSold product = new ProductsSold();
product.ItemNo = myReader.GetString(0);
product.ItemSize = myReader.GetString(1);
product.ItemPrice = myReader.GetDecimal(2);
product.UnitsSold = myReader.GetInt32(3);
context.ProductsSolds.InsertOnSubmit(product);
```

Comment: Thanks for the TIP, I noticed that its throwing an error on ItemPrice which is declared as decimal in database and in the Excel sheet its just in general format, I changed it to number with 2 decimals but still throws.

Comment: Format doesn't matter in excel. I think everything is a double. Try reading the last two values as doubles and casting before putting in the database.